# Docker shared volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a config directory that I send individual parts of to two images

```
config
  +-- service1
  +-- service2
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  service1:
  image: service1
  volumes:
    - config:/config
  build:
    - Dockerfile.service1

  service2:
    image: service2
    volumes:
      - config:/config
    build:
      - Dockerfile.service2

volumes:
  config:
    driver: local
```

Dockerfile.service1

```
COPY config/service1 /config/service1
```

Dockerfile.service2

```
COPY config/service2 /config/service2
```

**Problem** When starting both images with `docker-compose up` both images will see *either* `config/service1` or `config/service2`. How to solve this?

Comment: Why are you copying files in your Dockerfile *and* mounting a volume at that same directory? The volume will overlay anything at that location.

Comment: @BMitch The configuration i read-write so I use the volume to save written changes between runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems if two volumes are applied to the same directory only the contents of one volume will be visible.

The solution in this case was to create separate volumes

```
services:
  service1:
  image: service1
  volumes:
    - config1:/config
  build:
    - Dockerfile.service1

  service2:
    image: service2
    volumes:
      - config2:/config
    build:
      - Dockerfile.service2

volumes:
  config1:
    driver: local
  config2:
    driver: local
```